# Enlazar a un archivo en blade

Tags: laravel, blade, enlaces-ancla

Tengo un proyecto Laravel en el que he definido un disco en el `filesystems.php`, así:

```
'ficherosPdf' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/ficheros/pdf'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

En la ruta especificada tengo un documento PDF. Tengo que crear un enlace en una vista blade para acceder a ese documento. Lo primero que se me ha ocurrido es lo siguiente:

```
<a href="storage/app/ficheros/pdf/documento.pdf">
```

Sin embargo, obtengo un error 404

También he probado con:

```
<a href=asset("storage/app/ficheros/pdf/documento.pdf")>
```

Ahí obtengo un mensaje de que no es accesible la ubicación, así:

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /asset("storage/app/ficheros/pdf/documento.pdf") on this server.**

Creo que no debería bloquearme el acceso, ya que en `filesystems.php` definí la ubicación con visibilidad pública, como se ve arriba.

Cómo debo construir el enlace para acceder al fichero en la ubicación indicada? Me he asegurado de que el fichero realmente está ahí.

Answer (score 1):

`Storage` es una caperta privada, por lo cual no puedes acceder de manera directa con un link hacia el archivo.

Te recomiendo agregar una ruta para poder descargar cualesquier archivo alojado en tu Storage:

```
Route::get('storage/{archivo}', function ($archivo) {
    $public_path = public_path();
    $url = $public_path.'/storage/app/ficheros/pdf/'.$archivo;
    if (Storage::exists($archivo))//verificamos si el archivo existe y lo retornamos
    {
      return response()->download($url);
    }
    abort(404);     //si no se encuentra lanzamos un error 404.

});
```

Entonces solo tenemos que realizar el link de descarga:

```
<a href="{{url('storage/nombre_del_documento.pdf')}}"> descargar </a>
```

Con eso deberias de solucionar tu problema.

Comment: He probado este código, y me ocurre una cosa muy extraña. En la carpeta de almacenamiento tengo tres archivos pdf. En la vista tengo tres enlaces, uno para cada archivo. El primero me lo descarga, pero se descarga corrupto, y no se puede abrir (ya he comprobado que el archivo original está bien). Para los otros dos, me salta la página 404, aunque he comprobado que están en la misma ubicación. ¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario que agregues una ruta para la descarga de los archivos, puedes crear un enlace simbólico que conecte desde la carpeta `public` a la carpeta `storage`. Ejecuta el siguiente comando artisan en consola `php artisan make:storage`, este link que se crea conecta la carpeta `public` hacia `storage/app/public/`, por lo tanto te sugiero guardes los archivos a los que quieres acceder dentro de la carpeta `public` que se encuentra en `storage`:

```
'ficherosPdf' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public/ficheros/pdf'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Una vez que modificaste eso, ejecuta el comando `php artisan cache:clear` ya que el archivo `filesystems.php` guarda en caché su configuración. Después de haber ejecutado el comando ahora si ya puedes crear tu enlace, que quedaría de la siguiente forma (si tu archivo `.htaccess` está bien configurado):

`<a href="{{ asset('storage/ficheros/pdf/documento.pdf') }}">`

En ese enlace le estamos diciendo que en la carpeta `public` que se encuentra en raíz acceda al enlace simbólico `storage` y después continúas tu ruta a partir de lo que pones dentro de la carpeta `public` que se encuentra en `storage`.

Answer (score 0):

yo lo hice de esta forma y me funciono bien. como es el mismo durectorio conservo todos los archivos subidos, recorro la matriz. haciendo una verificación por ext .doc .pdf .rar..

```
@foreach($lecfiles as $fl)                  
                    <?php if(Str::endsWith($fl->file,['docx','.doc','.pdf', '.zip','.rar'])){?>                     
                                <a target="_blank" href="{{ Storage::url($fl->file)}}">{{$fl->name_file}}</a>
                    <?php }?>
                @endforeach
```